# AKSideMenu disable left pan

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

I am new in Swift and working on side menu I am using `AKSideMenu` So If any one had used that library please let me know how to disable side menu for only one `UIViewController` Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write in `viewWillAppear`

`self.sideMenuViewController?.panGestureEnabled = false` **For disable side menu.**

Write in `viewWillDisappear`

`self.sideMenuViewController?.panGestureEnabled = true` **For enable side menu.**